# Почему возникает ошибка Cannot POST и как её исправить? Как получить и обработать данные?

Tags: node.js, post, express

При нажатии кнопки появляется Cannot POST /index.ejs

Что ни так?

И ещё вопрос. У меня есть страница index.ejs, где вводятся данные и post.ejs, где будут отображаться данные. Как это сделать?

Мой проект выглядит вот так:

-views->index.ejs

-views->post.ejs

-app.js

app.js (в корневой директории)

```
const port = 3000;
var express = require ('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();
app.use [bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})];
app.use [bodyParser.json()];


app.get ("/", function(req,res){
    res.render ('index.ejs');
});
app.post("/", function (request, response) {
    if(!request.body) return response.sendStatus(400);
    console.log(request.body);
    response.send(`<h2>${request.body.fName} - ${request.body.sex} - ${request.body.select} </h2>`);
});

app.listen(port, function (){
    console.log ('Work on port: ' + port);
});
```

views/index.ejs (в папке)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="centerLayer" >
        <form action="index.ejs" method="post" >
            <div>  
                <b class = 'hd'>Full name:</b><br>
                <input type="text" name="fName" size="35" maxlength="60">
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="ChoiceMen" name="sex" value="men" checked>
            <label for="Choice1">Men</label>
            <input type="radio" id="ChoiceWomen" name="sex" value="women">
            <label for="Choice2">Women</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select name ="theSelect">
                    <option name ="Birthday" >Birthday</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

views/post.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>тест</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: может потому, что у вас отправка на .ejs идёт, а не на реальный адрес? Action должен в корень ссылаться

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Я поменяла на  C:/../views/index.ejs. Post не работает всё равно, в консоль не выводит. И пишет Not allowed to load local resource(

Comment: Возможно вы не понимаете как работает этот процесс в целом. Форма отправляет запрос на URL всегда, а не в файл, а вы ему задаёте имя шаблона. EJS к отправке данных вообще не относится. Данные принимаются по адресу "/" вашим app.js. Браузер, где будет ваша форма, вообще не знает, что на сервере ejs используется, он может только по URL отправить.